# Не обновляется метка на карте yandex maps api

Tags: yandex-maps-api, angular

Использую ангуляр.
Есть проблема не обновляется метка на карте yandex maps api.
кейс такой

1. нажимаем на сущность с координатами, из списка
2. координаты передаются карте через @Input()
3. карта показывает новую точку.

Проблема: показывается первая точка, нажимаем на другую, она не показывается пока не поменяешь зум карты или не поменяет центр карты.  Код компонента карты с показом точек:

```
export class MapShowTaskComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() position: MyPosition;
  myMap: MyMapModel;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ngOnInit");
  }

  private hidePoints() {
    console.log("hidePoints");
    this.myMap.data.geoObjects.get(0).removeAll();
  }

  public showPoints(): void {
    const points = {
      type: "FeatureCollection",
      features: []
    };

    points.features.push({
      type: "Feature",
      id: points.features.length,
      geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: this.position.coordinates
      }
    });
    console.log("showPoints", points);
    console.log("objectManager", this.myMap.data.geoObjects.get(0));
    this.myMap.data.geoObjects.get(0).add(points);
    this.myMap.data.setCenter(this.position.coordinates);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log("ngOnChanges", this.position);

    if (this.myMap) {
      this.hidePoints();
      this.showPoints();
    }
  }
}
```

Вот так создаю карту:

```
private initMap() {
    const self = this;
    console.log("initMap");
    // TODO ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
    this.myMap.data = new self.myMap.yaMap.data.Map(
      "my-map-id",
      {
        center: DEFAULT_COORDINATES,
        zoom: MAP_DEFAULT_ZOOM,
        controls: ["fullscreenControl", "geolocationControl"]
      },
      {
        yandexMapDisablePoiInteractivity: true,
        suppressMapOpenBlock: true
      }
    );

    // Создаем objectManager
    const objectManager = new self.myMap.yaMap.data.ObjectManager({
      // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
      clusterize: true,
      // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
      gridSize: 32,
      clusterDisableClickZoom: true
    });
    this.myMap.data.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `id: points.features.length,`

У вас у всех точек одинаковый `id`. `ObjectManager` требует уникальные `id` для объектов (смотрите [документацию](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager-docpage/#method_detail__add-param-objects))

> Сущность представляет собой объект с полями:
>
> - id – уникальный идентификатор объекта. Обязательное поле.
> - ...